# Can I give the same name for different Models in different apps?

Tags: python, django

Can I give the same name for different Models in different apps? and What conflicts can happen?

After I have a try.. I got this Error:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
playlist.playlist: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.playlist_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
audio_playlist.playlist: Accessor for field 'user' clashes with related field 'User.playlist_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user'.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Of course you can do that. There won't be any conflicts because tables are stored internally as `appname_modelname`; let's say you have a model named `Post` in an app named `blog` and a model named `Post` in an app named `messages`. Tables will be stored as `blog_post` and `messages_post`. Also, the python classes are named `project.blog.models.Post` and `project.messages.models.Post`, so no conflict here either.

**EDIT**: Also, to be able to import them both in one file, use something like this:

```
import blog.models.Post as BlogPost
import messages.models.Post as MessagesPost
```

(or any names that make sense)

Comment: And what gonna happen if you load both model in the one view? Or if you do command shell_plus for example?

Comment: make sure the names won't collide. by that I mean something like `import blog.models.Post as BlogPost` and `import message.models.Post as MessagesPost`

Comment: What about shell_plus it load models as they are... Does it give  me an error?

Comment: it won't give you an error; the worst thing that can happen is rewriting the Post object. Other than that, it behaves just like the script.

Comment: Do you suggest to not do that?, or its dos not matter?

Comment: @Pol if you need two objects with the same name it's normal to hold them with two different names.

Comment: To override the `shell_plus` behavior see this page: http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html#configuration

Comment: Nice Explanation, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's true that at the database level this will cause no issues.

**You WILL run into problems with your URL routes and internal view names, though!**

Assume you have two apps--"blog" and "comments" and each has a model named Message, and each Message model has a corresponding ModelViewSet (BlogMessageViewSet and CommentMessageViewSet, respectively)

The Django router will automatically name your view names `message-list`, `message-detail`, etc... with no regard for which app that model is in.  So you will have collisions after you load these into your router since you have two models named 'Message'.  For example, if in urls.py my router looked like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blog/message', BlogMessageViewSet)
router.register(r'comment/message', CommentMessageViewSet)
```

Then internally both the routes for /blog/message and /comment/message will point to /comment/message since that was registered last with the router and internally the view names will be `message-list`, `message-detail`, etc...

You can resolve this issue by giving a different base name to one of your views though like this:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'blog/message', BlogMessageViewSet, view_name='blogmessage')
router.register(r'comment/message', CommentMessageViewSet)
```

Though this will require you to explicit define the url as a HyperlinkedIdentityField on the serializer for BlogMessageViewSet if you are using a HyperlinkedModelSerializer and to make all references to this view in urlresolvers.reverse() or other url-based tools use the view name 'blockmessage.'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done the same thing in one of my projects.
If models have ForeignKey fields, like- BolgPost.author , then you have to give related_name to them.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='eu_author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score -4):

Django is built on Python. Each app has it's own namespace.