# django views in different folder conflicting model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have view files containing view functions in separate folders and they are both importing 2 different models having same name from different folders

```
/models/telephone_expense/transistion_history.py
/models/medical/transistion_history.py

/views/medical/<view_files>
/views/telephone/<view_files>
```

Error

```
 RuntimeError: Conflicting 'transitionhistory' models in application 'reimbursement': <class 'reimbursement.models.medical.transition_history.TransitionHistory'> and <class 'reimbursement.models.telephone_expense.transition_history.TransitionHistory'>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3999010/2875586) can help you.
You can have models with the same name in different apps but when you import them you should give them different names with the as keyword.
You can fix this by fixing your imports like:

```
from reimbursement.models import transitionhistory as ReimTranHistory
```

Comment: Yeah, it can be solved by that way but I have a single app containing 2 modules medical and telephone expense, both have 2 models with same name ie TransitionHistory.

Now in views folder i have to import all the views fucntion in __init__.py, there it is creating conflict errors

Comment: why not have a parent model and then in each module you can inherit from that