# How to call app name when calling a one to one model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my apps:

```
user
students
university
```

Now, how to use same names for two model ? for instance each student and university have profile model. At first when i do "Class Profile" under student

```
It gets a new table named student_profile

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

now in students app i can user 

student_profile = request.user.profile
```

But how to do the same for university ? The table gets created like

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

But how to use on views ?

```
university_profile = request.user.profile
```

How to use the app name when calling `user.request.profile` ?

Comment: Did you mean `request.user`? How is a user related to a university?

Comment: ya its a typo, my bad ! And i have a common user  table with login credits and each role has different profile @bdbd

Comment: Can you share your models if possible

Comment: its a huge model, if its okay check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998984/can-i-give-the-same-name-for-different-models-in-different-apps     ( this is exactly what i ment )

Comment: I see. But it seems both the profiles are connected to the user. You can just share the university profile, student profile, and user models (just show the foreign keys)

Comment: I have added the models

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236357/discussion-between-sixovov947-and-bdbd).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a unique related name for the one to one field, to be able to distinguish between the two profiles from `user`, so:

For university:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='university_profile')
```

For student:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile)
```

Then you should be able to access both profiles from `user`:

```
print(request.user.student_profile)
print(request.user.university_profile)
```

Comment: ya, I am aware of  related name, but is that the only way ? or is there any other ways available ?

Comment: I don't think django can automatically change `request.user.profile` to the type that you need without doing some manual thing. You need to distinguish between either student or university anyway so I would suggest to use related name to also help make it readable